# Menu - Style ul / li to be width depend on text lenght

Tags: html, css

i am trying to style my menu. I had a working code but notied that parent div is smaller then child div. I am pretty sure its not right so i try to edit it a bit but now i have a problem with it. It looks like:
[image]

As you can see last part of menu "FLASHOVKY" is on another line, and all li is same width dispite the fact text is different lenght.

CSS:

```
#menu {
    background-image: url('images/menubg.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 44px;
    width: 983px;
    font-family: Arial;
    margin-left: 22px;
}
#menu ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#menu ul li {
    color: #f7f7f7;
    height: 44px;
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 100px;
}

#menu ul li a {
    background-image: url('images/menu_spacer.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top right;
    color: #f7f7f7;
    float: left;
    padding: 14px 15px; /* Disadvantage: you will have to adjust this padding MANUALLY */
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 85px;
}
#menu ul li:last-child a {
    background: none;
}
#menu ul li a:after {
    background-image: url('images/sipka.png');
    content: '';
    width: 10px;
    height: 8px;
    margin-left: 8px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <nav id="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">GAMESITES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">HRY</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SERVERY</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CLANKY</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FORUM</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">DOWNLOADS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">BLOGY</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FLASHOVKY</a></li>                                                
      </ul> 
  </nav>
```

Can somebody help me with that guys?
p.s. Live demo : http://funedit.com/andurit/try11/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1]** You can fix this by setting `box-sizing:border-box;`. The issue is the padding on your `<a>` tags, it's causing the content to overflow because the padding and border are placed outside of the content box.

**2]** To fix the spacing issue, you need to add a `float: left;` to `#menu ul li`. The reason for this is because the `<a>` tags nested in `#menu ul li` are floated left. That's why the links were offset.

**Change this:**

```
#menu ul li {
    color: #f7f7f7;
    height: 44px;
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 100px;
}

#menu ul li a {
    background-image: url('images/menu_spacer.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top right;
    color: #f7f7f7;
    float: left;
    padding: 14px 15px; /* Disadvantage: you will have to adjust this padding MANUALLY */
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 85px;
}
```

**To this:**

```
#menu ul li {
    color: #f7f7f7;
    height: 44px;
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 100px;
    float:left; /* Add this float to remove extra space */
}

#menu ul li a {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */

    background-image: url('images/menu_spacer.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top right;
    color: #f7f7f7;
    float: left;
    padding: 14px 15px; /* Disadvantage: you will have to adjust this padding MANUALLY */
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 85px;
}
```

Comment: Hey man, your code is actualy really working and helping me, but  just noticed that like 5 pixels around spacer is not click able and it should be just 1 (the spacer) can u help me with that as well?

Comment: Hang on, I see it now. Investigating.

Comment: GOT IT. Add a float:left; to #menu ul li. That will remove the space. Updated code in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try playing around with the   min-width values in your css.

Answer (score 0):

```
#menu {
    background-image: url('images/menubg.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 44px;
    width: 983px;
    font-family: Arial;
    margin-left: 22px;
}
#menu ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#menu ul li {
    color: #f7f7f7;
    height: 44px;
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 100px;          // this property causing you to make all box of same size and it occupie the 100px wether text is small or large
}

#menu ul li a {
    background-image: url('images/menu_spacer.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top right;
    color: #f7f7f7;
    float: left;
    padding: 14px 15px; /* Disadvantage: you will have to adjust this padding MANUALLY */
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 85px;    // dont fix width 
}
#menu ul li:last-child a {
    background: none;
}
#menu ul li a:after {
    background-image: url('images/sipka.png');
    content: '';
    width: 10px;
    height: 8px;
    margin-left: 8px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: dont fix min width to 100px make it less like 30px tht will make autometic take max width to size of text

Answer (score 0):

Use float:left instead of display block..and only use height if you need..yes inline and float:left has for different use..but may be you will like..

```
#menu {
    background-image: url('images/menubg.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 44px;
    width: 983px;
    font-family: Arial;
    border:1px solid;
    margin-left: 22px;
}
#menu ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width:100%;
}
#menu ul li {
    color: #000;
    height: 44px;
    float:left;
    min-width: 100px;
}

#menu ul li a {
    background-image: url('images/menu_spacer.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top right;
    color: #000;
    float: left;
    padding: 14px 15px; /* Disadvantage: you will have to adjust this padding MANUALLY */
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 85px;
}
#menu ul li:last-child a {
    background: none;
}
#menu ul li a:after {
    background-image: url('images/sipka.png');
    content: '';
    width: 10px;
    margin-left: 8px;
    display: block;
}
```